# Building on iPhone with provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am having a lot of trouble setting up my Xcode project so that it builds on my iPhone.

I have followed all the steps in the Development Provisioning Assistant, but I always end up with a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.test' could

not be found Error when I build.

My app identifier on the provisioning profile is 93QA3MXYM7.com.test.MediaAccess. In my

info.plist file the bundle identifier is com.test.I have tired pretty much every

combination of 93QA3MXYM7.com.test.MediaAccess that makes sense and I can think of, but I

always get the same error, saying that a provisioning profile doesn't match!

I am very confused as what is the application name, the project name, the bundle name, the

app ID description, the bundle ID, and the bundle seed ID. In the Development Provisioning

Assistant, when you create an AppID, there is only the app description field. When you

create an AppID through the regular interface, there are 3 fields! Which ones should match?

Could I get an example please? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put com.test.MediaAccess to "Bundle identifier" property. then go to select settings of your project, find **Code Signing Identity** section and select the right profile for your Debug configuration (the right provisioning profile should be downloaded and set up)

Comment: So, I started fresh, the provisioning profile's app identifier is now 93QA3MXYM7.com.testbundle, the appID is 93QA3MXYM7.com.testbundle.myApp2. I set the bundle identifier to "com.testbundle", set the right profile for the code signing identity, and I still get the same error

Comment: @DavidMenard try com.testbundle.myApp2 as the bundle identifier

Comment: @DavidMenard "the provisioning profile's app identifier is now 93QA3MXYM7.com.testbundle" - what does it mean? where do you see this? you set up Bundle Identifier (App ID Suffix) once - when you create an App ID. and then you use the same suffix (com.domainname.appname - com.testbundle.myApp2) as a bundle indentifier for your project

Comment: The "93QA3MXYM7.com.testbundle" identifier shows up when I select the  provisioning profile in the organizer window. When I create an AppID, I am required to choose a bundle seed ID, which is, in my case, the 93QA3MXYM7 (Team ID). As mentionned, I tried pretty much all combinations of bundle IDs I could think of, so the problem is not that they don`t match, but that XCode cannot associate them together.

Comment: I ended up following a different guide that told me to click on "refresh" in the organizer windows after selecting the provisioning profile. The profile synched up, I was asked for my username & password and all was well